# How to draw TrueTypeFont when using Iw2d in Marmalade?

Tags: marmalade

In a game done with Iw2D I would like to use TTF fonts, which are supported by IwGx module.
I read that it is doable to use IwGxFont module with Iw2D, but I must be missing something as
the text doesn't appear. It compiles and runs, just there is no text.

Code:

```
Iw2DInit();
DPI::dpiInit();
IwResManagerInit();
IwGxFontInit();
IwGetResManager()->LoadGroup("IwGxFontTTF.group");
font = (CIwGxFont*)IwGetResManager()->GetResNamed("Serif_6", "CIwGxFont");
...
while (!s3eDeviceCheckQuitRequest()) {
    s3ePointerUpdate();
    s3eKeyboardUpdate();
    if (s3eKeyboardGetState(s3eKeyAbsBSK) & S3E_KEY_STATE_DOWN) {
        break;
    }

    current_time = s3eTimerGetMs();
    const float dt = (current_time - last_frame_time)/1000.0f;
    last_frame_time = current_time;

    Iw2DSurfaceClear(0xffffffff);
    game->draw(dt);

    IwGxFontSetCol(0xffa0a0a0);
    IwGxFontSetRect(CIwRect(10,40,(int16)IwGxGetScreenWidth()-20,40));
    IwGxFontSetAlignmentVer(IW_GX_FONT_ALIGN_BOTTOM);
    IwGxFontSetFont(font);
    IwGxFontDrawText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
    IwGxFlush();
    Iw2DSurfaceShow();

    s3eDeviceYield(0);
    logger.log(dt);
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Given code was missing call Iw2DFinishDrawing. Should be:

```
Iw2DSurfaceClear(0xffffffff);
game->draw(dt);
Iw2DFinishDrawing();

IwGxFontSetCol(0xffa0a0a0);
IwGxFontSetRect(CIwRect(10,40,(int16)IwGxGetScreenWidth()-20,40));
IwGxFontSetAlignmentVer(IW_GX_FONT_ALIGN_BOTTOM);
IwGxFontSetFont(font);
IwGxFontDrawText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
IwGxFlush();
Iw2DSurfaceShow();
```

Comment: Thanx I had the same issues and I resolved it with Iw2DFinishDrawing.

Answer (score 2):

Well I just know that you've to use `FontBuilder` tool to create .gx files for fonts and can use those fonts only. The `IwGxFont` module works only for .gx font files. The method you are using can be used with gx fonts only.

<strike>So if you want to use TTF fonts, either there's any other method or there's no other method at all except converting fonts to GX format.</strike>

**Edit:-**

After reading the api, I came to know that there's another method to use TTF fonts, although your problem is already solved. I thought I should correct my answer. The method is to use ttf fonts into group files with predefined size and styles, like how the fontbuilder tool does while creating gx fonts. Adding the following lines in the group will allow the ttf fonts to be able to load from IwResManager.

```
CIwGxFont
{
    name "Serif_8"

    ttf ".\Fonts\serif.ttf"
    ttfPointSize 8
}
```

Comment: Most of this code is copied from example: examples/IwGxFont/IwGxFontTTF, which appears to use Serif.ttf file as font file.

Comment: Made the correction. Thanks for pointing it out, I got to know about one more method of loading fonts.